# How do I configure mathjax for iPython notebooks?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, mathjax

I'm trying to find a way for mathjax to not use STIX fonts for math in my iPython notebook. Instead, I'd much rather have it use the 'TeX' fonts. According to the documentation for Mathjax I should use:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "HTML-CSS": {
    preferredFont: "TeX"
  }
});
```

That being said, I'm not sure where to put this. I've already tried putting this chunk of code into my custom.js file pertaining to my own ipython profile, but it doesn't work. Ideally, I'd like to make ipython profile specific adjustments for mathjax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple test to make sure that you're getting the configuration correct is to change `preferredFont: "TeX"` to `scale: 200`.  Then save and reload a notebook.  The math should be obviously way bigger than before.  So assuming that worked, it means your `config.js` is doing what it needs to.

Now, more to the point, try adding another line so that your configuration looks like

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  "HTML-CSS": {
    availableFonts: ["TeX"],
    preferredFont: "TeX",
  }
});
```

Don't forget to fully refresh the notebook page after you've saved that.  This overrides (what I'm guessing is) the [default value of that `availableFonts` variable](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/HTML-CSS.html), which would allow STIX if mathjax can't find TeX.  I'm not sure why it seems to ignore the preferred font, but this seems more like a mathjax issue than an ipython issue.

So now, if it still isn't in TeX font (which mathjax seems to call `MathJax_Math-Italic.otf`, or similar), I would guess that mathjax just can't find that font, and may have fallen back on something else.  If that is the case, there's something messed up about your mathjax installation.

Comment: where does `config.js` go?

Comment: if in `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js` it does not work

Comment: I guess something has changed.  The `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js` file does actually get read, which you can verify by putting some `console.log` message in there.  But the mathjax configuration seems to have no effect.  They seem to change the way configuration works every few minutes.  It's very frustrating.

Comment: yeah, from what I gather the problem isn't the configuration, it's the fact that the TeX fonts actually aren't there by default (see my answer and Stefan Shi's answer)

Comment: I think it's more than that, though, because other configurations don't work, even if they don't rely on fonts.  For example, I have a `TeX: {Macros: {}}` section, and none of the macros so defined are available.  There's no message in the log about this or anything...

Answer (score 11):

I recently had the exact problem. I really don't like the default `STIX-Web` font to render equation. After experimenting for a little while, I found a way to change the MathJax font in Jupyter Notebook. My Jupyter Notebook version is 4.3.1 and it is shipped with Anaconda. I assume the solutions for other versions should be similar.

I tried to edit `custom.js` both in `/notebook/static/custom/custom.js` and `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`. Doesn't work. I also tried to edit `mathjaxutils.js`. It does nothing. Finaly I saw this post https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/109. I realize Jupyter uses `main.min.js` to read `MathJax` configuration. So here is the solutions:

- Download `MathJax`(https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax) from `Github`.
- Unzip the `MathJax` file and go into the folder

  - copy `jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/TeX` into directoy `../notebook/static/components/MathJax/jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/`
  - copy `fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX` into `../notebook/static/components/MathJax/fonts/HTML-CSS/`
- open `../notebook/static/notebook/js/main.min.js`, search for `availableFonts`. It should be around line 14894. Change it to

  ```
  ...
  availableFonts: ["STIX-Web","TeX"],
  imageFont: null;
  preferredFont: "TeX",
  webFont: "TeX"
  ...
  ```
- Refresh the notebook.

Comment: I upvoted, but this is a monkeypatching answer rather than the right answer (which seems to be unknown)

Comment: for what it's worth, MathJax no longer has this structure; you'll have to run `git checkout legacy-v2` to access MathJax v2 source

Answer (score 4):

Jupyter ships with its own (smaller) version of MathJax. This is why it is not able to find the (Computer Modern) 'TeX' font -- there only is the STIX font.

To fix this, I was able to do the following:

1. Download [MathJax 2.7](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/releases/tag/2.7.5) and copy the `jax` directory.
2. Replace Jupyter's `jax` directory with the copied one:

- For the default environment: `~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/static/components/MathJax/jax`
- For a different environment: `~/anaconda3/envs/<ENVIRONMENT>/lib/python3.7/site-packages/notebook/static/components/MathJax/jax`

3. Restart Jupyter, right-click on a piece of math and switch the 'Math Renderer' to SVG.

(Adjust python version in path if yours is not 3.7; If you are using miniconda the path should be `~/opt/miniconda3/lib/...`)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at some of the [numericalmooc](https://github.com/numerical-mooc/numerical-mooc) lessons such as [this one](http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/numerical-mooc/numerical-mooc/blob/master/lessons/01_phugoid/01_01_Phugoid_Theory.ipynb) where the MathJax configuration is [included through a `css` file](https://github.com/numerical-mooc/numerical-mooc/blob/master/styles/numericalmoocstyle.css) which is imported at some point in the notebook.

Answer (score 2):

I've tweaked @Stefan Shi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42446768/44330) to something a little easier, at least if you have the command-line `svn` installed.

- Put the following into a script file called `install_tex_fonts` (`install_tex_fonts.bat` in Windows-land):

  ```
  svn export https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/trunk/fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff fonts/HTML-CSS/TeX/woff
  svn export https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax/trunk/jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/TeX jax/output/HTML-CSS/fonts/TeX
  ```
- Move the script file into `{PYTHON}/Lib/site-packages/notebook/static/components/MathJax`  where `{PYTHON}` is the root directory where you installed Python
- Open a shell (command prompt) in this directory
- Run the script by typing `install_tex_fonts` (or `./install_tex_fonts` on *nix systems; I guess you also have to `chmod a+x` it)
- Add the following section in your `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js` file (the `$([IPython.events]).on('app_initialized.NotebookApp')` line should already be there):

  ```
  $([IPython.events]).on('app_initialized.NotebookApp', function(){

    MathJax.Hub.Config({
      "HTML-CSS": {
          availableFonts: ["TeX"],
          preferredFont: "TeX",
          webFont: "TeX"
      }
     });
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Following @Ian's information, you can get your initial HTML-CSS MathJax configuration from python with the below code (demjson is a soft requirement which allows us to partially process json in a javascript file: `pip install demjson`):

```py
import sys
from pathlib import Path

MathJax_cfg_pth = (
    Path(sys.executable).parents[0] /
    # below path may differ
    'Lib/site-packages/notebook/static/components/MathJax/jax/output/HTML-CSS/config.js'
)
with open(MathJax_cfg_pth, 'r') as f:
    MathJax_cfg = f.read()

import demjson
start_cfg = MathJax_cfg.find("config:{") + 7
open_braces = 0
for i, c in enumerate(MathJax_cfg[start_cfg:]):
    if c == '{':
        open_braces += 1
    elif c == '}':
        if open_braces == 0:
            break
        open_braces -= 1
initial_configuration = demjson.decode(
    MathJax_cfg[
        start_cfg : start_cfg + i
    ].replace("(", "'(").replace(")", ")'")
)
```

Having this will be helpful if you want to revert any changes without restarting your notebook kernel. For the curious, my `initial_configuration` is here: https://pastebin.com/JkatcrAC

Next we can update a HTML-CSS MathJax setting in our current runtime by displaying HTML containing a short script. If you wanted to update the size of HTML-CSS displays you could use the following function:

```py
from IPython.core.display import HTML
MathJax_scale_script = """
<script>
    MathJax.Hub.Config({
        "HTML-CSS": {
            scale: %s
        }
    });
</script>
"""
def update_Math_size(size):
    # 100 is default
    display(HTML(MathJax_scale_script%size))
```

For example, `update_Math_size(200)` for double the size, and `update_Math_size(100)` to revert back to my default setting.