# Converting IPython notebook mhchem markdown to pdf

Tags: pdf, latex, jupyter-notebook, mathjax

Having figured out how to insert mhchem into MathJax expressions in an IPython notebook, (from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122210/how-do-i-get-mathjax-to-enable-the-mhchem-extension-in-ipython-notebook)) I was pretty pleased until I wanted to convert the notebook to PDF.  My markdown cell contains:

```
$\require{mhchem}$
$\ce{CH2O2->[k_1]H2 + CO2}$
```

But attempting to convert the notebook to PDF using the following terminal command

```
ipython nbconvert untitled.ipynb --to pdf
```

results in an `! Undefined Control Sequence` error - similar to this [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213320/undefined-control-sequence-error-with-mhchem-and-hyperref-ce-within-section).  However the solution proposed (`\texorpdfstring`) isn't recognized by the MathJax interpreter in the markdown cell.  Any ideas or workarounds to resolve the issue?

IPython 3.0.0 /MiKTeX 2.9 /win7x86

Comment: Could you be more specific about the problem, maybe share an example notebook and/or post the relevant latex output. Have you placed the \ce in a heading cell?

Comment: you can check out the notebook (a single markdown cell) here:  http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/chepyle/ipynb-test/blob/master/mhchem_test.ipynb

Comment: Does your tex document compiles fine if you comment out the `$\require{mhchem}$` part?

Comment: No, because there are ``\ce`` in the notebook cells then and latex will complain that ``\ce`` is undefined control sequence (obviously ``\usepackage{mhchem}`` is not added on nbconvert).

Comment: As my edit has been rejected, trying to specify the issue: error message is ``! Undefined control sequence. l.230 \[\require {mhchem}\]``. I very strongly suppose that this is the real error message of the OP. My system is (comparable to his) IPython3.2/LiveTex 2015/Win7x86/pandoc 0.15.

Answer (score 3):

To include the `mhchem` package you need to create a custom template. Moreover it is necessary to handle the `\require` mathjax command which is not available in pdflatex.

A possible template (`chemtempl.tplx`) could look like

```
((*- extends 'article.tplx' -*))

((* block packages *))
((( super() )))
\usepackage{mhchem}
((* endblock packages *))

((* block commands *))
((( super() )))
% disable require command
\newcommand{\require}[1]{}
((* endblock commands *))
```

This template extends to default article template by overriding the package and commands block. The `super` call is similar to the python command and includes the original block content.
The `\require` command is tackled by defining a new command which takes one argument and does nothing -> this way it can remain in the notebook.

The template is used like

```
jupyter nbconvert --template chemtempl.tplx --to pdf notebook.ipynb
```

if you are using IPython 3.x just replace `jupyter` with `ipython`.

To use the template also with the *download as pdf* feature in the notebook,
a config file has to be used. To this end create a config file (`.ipython/profile_default/ipython_config.py` for IPython 3.x or `.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py` for IPython 4.x (Jupyter)) with the following content:

```py
c = get_config()
c.LatexExporter.template_path = ['/home/path/to/template/']
c.LatexExporter.template_file = 'chemtempl.tplx'
```

After restarting Jupyter the new config should be loaded and the template be used.

(I guess for IPython 3.x the file could also be named `ipython_notebook_config.py` but currently I have no 3.x version to test this.)

Comment: IPython 3.1 (notebook) seems to have neither the command line flag ``--template`` nor ``--post``. Can you point to jupyter documentation where this is explained?

Comment: sorry my mistake! It has to be ``ipython nbconvert ...``. Edited my answer.

Comment: And this is the [documentation of nbconvert](http://nbconvert.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: Ok, thanks, ``--post pdf`` does not work (misses a library), but ``--to pdf`` does. Is it possible to specify the template inclusion from the notebook interface?

Comment: Sorry again, the ``--post pdf`` call is from ipython 2.x since 3.x it's ``--to pdf``. Yes, you can specify the template to be used when downloading a notebook as pdf. I'll update my answer in a few hours.

Comment: I think you have earned the bounty already, but as you seem to be a knowledgeable jupyter user: Do you see a possibility to set the configuration for a specific notebook from **within** a notebook (analoguous to the ``$\require{mhchem}$`` directive?

Comment: this is a tricky question :) currently I don't know any way, but I will dig into this a bit deeper, maybe there is one.

Comment: I awarded the bounty because it is fully deserved. -1 for me, because I did not require the solution for the question to be "inline" in the notebook.

Comment: I had created an issue [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/356) and asked for advice how to include the template information in the notebook. However, it is currently not possible due to security issues.

Answer (score 0):

After failing to follow the answer above, I discovered an easy workaround.

You can simply edit the default LaTex template used by nbconvert to include

```
\usepackage{mhchem}
```

in the preamble. This means that all chem equations will work just like any math equations in your notebook.

For me (macOS) the template was found at `/Users/USER/opt/anaconda3/share/jupyter/nbconvert/templates/latex/base.tex.j2`

I'm not sure if this was related, but I got a few compile errors once I modified the preamble related to spaces next to my `$` in math blocks. It was all fixed after making sure there was no space within the `$`'s and one space outside them.