# Loading AMSmath explicitly in IPython notebook causes "[Math Processing Error]"

Tags: latex, ipython, jupyter-notebook, mathjax

I am a relatively new IPython Notebook user and I am using IPython 3.2.1. So upfront, my apologies if I did not read some documentation carefully!

I am trying to typeset some LaTeX in my Notebook intended for a presentation. I tried to utilize MathJax capabilities better than what's (supposedly) available by default and so tried incorporating other extensions that come with MathJax explicitly. In particular, I tried getting my IPython Notebook to load AMScd.js, AMSsymbols.js and unicode.js through the following sequence of steps:

1. Obtain the .js files for these extensions from the latest MathJax (v2.5) source
2. Add them to my ~/.ipython/nbextensions
3. Modify custom.js in ~/.ipython/profile_<mine>/static/custom by appending `IPython.load_extensions("AMScd")`, etc.

Now, all these work fine, and I am able to typeset commutative diagrams nicely in my IPython notebook. So, while at all this, I decided to also include/load AMSmath.js that comes along with MathJax and this is problematic. (To me, this seems like a natural thing to do given that other extensions work well!) However, attempting to include AMSmath.js via `IPython.load_extensions("AMSmath")` causes LaTeX math in my Notebook to display *[Math Processing Error]* everywhere. Here's my minimal example and the output with and without including `IPython.load_extensions("AMSmath")`.

**Markup:**

```
## A minimal working example

\\[
\Delta u = f \text{ on } \Omega
\\]
```

(I would totally like to include images here, alas, my not being an active participant in the community here leaves me with not even 10 reputation!)

So, what am I missing here? Why is this inclusion of AMSmath problematic? Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work without extra configuration. Have a look [here](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/stable/notebook/notebook.html#markdown-cells).

Your example in a **markdown** cell should be

(If you want the equation inline you can use $...$)

```
Inline equation $\Delta u = f \text{ on } \Omega$
```

(Or if you want the equation centered in their own line you can use $$...$$)

```
$$\Delta u = f \text{ on } \Omega$$
```

The result of both snippets in the same markdown cell is rendered as:
[image]

How it is loaded?

IPython/Jupyter notebook preloads some [MathJax extensions including the extension you want to load](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/0d68bbb1afbf3bc5b20b921efe503d48388eb959/setupbase.py#L150). This extension is not an IPYthon/Jupyter extension so it shouldn't work if you try to load this MathJax extension as an IPython/Jupyter extension. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122210/how-do-i-get-mathjax-to-enable-the-mhchem-extension-in-ipython-notebook) to know more about how to load other MathJax extensions.

Comment: I agree that it works without including AMSmath, and I am really sorry I forgot to state this in my question. However, I couldn't figure out why including AMSmath.js was leading to problems. Is there some sort of conflict between the default loading of it by IPython Notebook, and the explicit inclusion?