# How to Enable MathJax Upgreek in jupyter/ipython notebook?

Tags: ipython, jupyter, mathjax

I have reviewed various related questions including

- [How do I get MathJax to enable the mhchem extension in ipython notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21122210/how-do-i-get-mathjax-to-enable-the-mhchem-extension-in-ipython-notebook)
- [IPython (Jupyter) MathJaX preamble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28435997/ipython-jupyter-mathjax-preamble)

but I cannot get it to work...

My test case is simply

```
from IPython.display import display, HTML, Math, Latex    
display(Math(r'\uppi'))
```

expecting upright $\pi$ but currently getting just '\uppi' back raw.

I have tried the following using cell magic

```
%%javascript
<script type="text/Javascript">
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  loader: {load: ['[tex]/upgreek']},
  tex: {packages: {'[+]': ['upgreek']}}
});
</script>
```

which generates `Javascript Error: Unexpected token '<'`

```
%%javascript
MathJax.Hub.Config({
  loader: {load: ['[tex]/upgreek']},
  tex: {extensions: ['require.js'], packages: {'[+]': ['upgreek']}}
});
```

which throws no error but doesn't seem to have any effect

```
%%javascript
window.MathJax = {
  loader: {load: ['[tex]/upgreek']},
  tex: {packages: {'[+]': ['upgreek']}}
};
```

which also does not seem to have the desired effect

**Question**: I don't want to modify configuration/javascript files outside the notebook. How can I enable MathJax upgreek dynamically in a jupyter notebook?

(Currently on jupyterlab 3.2.2, python 3.8.10 under Windows 10)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not address the OP's fundamental issue, which relates to the control of the installation of MathJax extensions in jupyter, but it does address the objective: to alter the rendered appearance of greek symbols (but can be applied to other font-related needs as well)

**Updated**
The following will create TeX macros for all upper and lower case greek characters, as also available in Upgreek if it could be installed.

```
from IPython.display import display, Math

# Using codes from https://unicode-table.com/en/sets/greek-symbols/, create dictionaries of unicodes keyed by character names
grLcUpChars = [rf'\unicode{{{code}}}' for code in range(0x3B1, 0x3CA) if code != 0x3C2]  # omit 'final sigma'
grUcUpChars = [rf'\unicode{{{code}}}' for code in range(0x391, 0x3AA) if code != 0x3A2]  # omit omitted code for 'final sigma' in uppercase
grCharNames = ['alpha', 'beta', 'gamma', 'delta', 'epsilon', 'zeta', 'eta', 'theta', 'iota', 'kappa', 'lambda',
               'mu', 'nu', 'xi', 'omicron', 'pi', 'rho', 'sigma', 'tau', 'upsilon', 'phi', 'chi', 'psi', 'omega']

zipIt = zip(grCharNames, grLcUpChars)
grLcUpDict = dict(zipIt)
zipIt = zip(grCharNames, grUcUpChars)
grUcUpDict = dict(zipIt)

# Generate the MathJax code to create 'macro' definitions for upright greek characters
# See e.g. https://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/input/tex/macros.html
# Paste output text from $ to $ inclusive into a markdown cell and execute it
print('$')
for grCharName in grCharNames:
    print(fr'    \def\Up{grCharName}{{{{{grLcUpDict[grCharName]}}}}}')

for grCharName in grCharNames:
    print(fr'    \def\Up{grCharName.title()}{{{{{grUcUpDict[grCharName]}}}}}')

print('$')
```

which produces the TeX macros for a Markdown cell:

```
$
    \def\Upalpha{{\unicode{945}}}
    \def\Upbeta{{\unicode{946}}}
    \def\Upgamma{{\unicode{947}}}
    \def\Updelta{{\unicode{948}}}
    \def\Upepsilon{{\unicode{949}}}
    \def\Upzeta{{\unicode{950}}}
    \def\Upeta{{\unicode{951}}}
    \def\Uptheta{{\unicode{952}}}
    \def\Upiota{{\unicode{953}}}
    \def\Upkappa{{\unicode{954}}}
    \def\Uplambda{{\unicode{955}}}
    \def\Upmu{{\unicode{956}}}
    \def\Upnu{{\unicode{957}}}
    \def\Upxi{{\unicode{958}}}
    \def\Upomicron{{\unicode{959}}}
    \def\Uppi{{\unicode{960}}}
    \def\Uprho{{\unicode{961}}}
    \def\Upsigma{{\unicode{963}}}
    \def\Uptau{{\unicode{964}}}
    \def\Upupsilon{{\unicode{965}}}
    \def\Upphi{{\unicode{966}}}
    \def\Upchi{{\unicode{967}}}
    \def\Uppsi{{\unicode{968}}}
    \def\Upomega{{\unicode{969}}}
    \def\UpAlpha{{\unicode{913}}}
    \def\UpBeta{{\unicode{914}}}
    \def\UpGamma{{\unicode{915}}}
    \def\UpDelta{{\unicode{916}}}
    \def\UpEpsilon{{\unicode{917}}}
    \def\UpZeta{{\unicode{918}}}
    \def\UpEta{{\unicode{919}}}
    \def\UpTheta{{\unicode{920}}}
    \def\UpIota{{\unicode{921}}}
    \def\UpKappa{{\unicode{922}}}
    \def\UpLambda{{\unicode{923}}}
    \def\UpMu{{\unicode{924}}}
    \def\UpNu{{\unicode{925}}}
    \def\UpXi{{\unicode{926}}}
    \def\UpOmicron{{\unicode{927}}}
    \def\UpPi{{\unicode{928}}}
    \def\UpRho{{\unicode{929}}}
    \def\UpSigma{{\unicode{931}}}
    \def\UpTau{{\unicode{932}}}
    \def\UpUpsilon{{\unicode{933}}}
    \def\UpPhi{{\unicode{934}}}
    \def\UpChi{{\unicode{935}}}
    \def\UpPsi{{\unicode{936}}}
    \def\UpOmega{{\unicode{937}}}
$
```

For clarity & test, in another cell, this will list the defined macro names and display the upper and lower case alphabets

```
grLcAlphabetMathJax = [fr'\Up{grCharName}' for grCharName in grCharNames]
grUcAlphabetMathJax = [fr'\Up{grCharName.title()}' for grCharName in grCharNames]
display(grLcAlphabetMathJax)
display(grUcAlphabetMathJax)
display(Math(''.join(grLcAlphabetMathJax)))
display(Math(''.join(grUcAlphabetMathJax)))
```

Thereby effectively reproducing Upgreek; skipping the lists its output is:

αβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρστυφχψω
ΑΒΓΔΕΖΗΘΙΚΛΜΝΞΟΠΡΣΤΥΦΧΨΩ

**Superseded Original**
Workaround: referring to [this excellent MathJax/TeX documentation](https://www.onemathematicalcat.org/MathJaxDocumentation/TeXSyntax.htm) we find the \unicode instruction for MathJax, and via [this site](https://graphemica.com/%CF%80) the codes for an upright Pi symbol (as example).

This then allows the following in a notebook cell, after `from IPython.display import display, HTML, Math, Latex`

```
display(Math(r'\unicode[Segoe UI]{x03C0}'))
```

which generates `π`

whereas

```
display(Math(r'\unicode[familySTIXMathJax_Normal-italic]{x03C0}'))
```

generates an italicised  (that attempting to switch to familySTIXMathJax_Normal does not seem to affect!?)

and ordinary `display(Math(r'\pi'))` generates